# How to center an image in NPM README?

Tags: node.js, npm, markdown, readme

### Problem

I have a project fully documented and with a README which has the logo centered:

https://github.com/Fl4m3Ph03n1x/fs-error-logger/blob/master/README.md

The code I am using for this is the following:

```
<p align="center">
    <img src="./logos/logo_no_wm.png" >
</p>
```

After reading NPMs documentation, I had the strong impression this same code should work on NPM's markdown:

https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown/pull/242

However, if you check my NPM project, you can see the logo is not centered:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-error-logger

### Question

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a bug or an intentional decision by the developers. I suggest [filing a bug report](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown/issues/new).

A view of the page's source code reveals the following HTML for that image:

```
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fl4m3Ph03n1x/fs-error-logger/HEAD/logos/logo_no_wm.png" />
<p></p>
```

There are a couple things to note there. First, the image is not wrapped in a `p` tag, which is weird. Second, there is an empty `p` element immediately following. This could be a bug in their system, or an artifact of their HTML sanitation.

According to an HTML comment in the HTML source, [marky-markdown](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown) is the markdown parser used. That project's documentation [states](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown#what-it-does) in part:

> #### What it does
>
> - Parses markdown with [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it), a fast and [commonmark-compliant](http://commonmark.org/) parser.
> - Removes broken and malicious user input with [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html)

It then continues with a bunch of other post-processing steps. I checked and markdown-it passes the raw HTML through just fine, so presumably one of the post-processors is altering the output in some way. Or possibly, marky-markdown's modification of the markdown-it parser has broken something.

What I don't know is if this was an intentional decision by the marky-markdown developers or a bug. If it was intentional, then you may not ever be able to get your desired behavior. Either way, [filing a bug report](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown/issues/new) is the best way to get any answer.

### EDIT

For future reference, and for anyone else encountering this problem, the bug report [is here](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown/issues/404). The response is that this is in fact a bug and a [fix is already pending](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown/pull/405).

Comment: Alright, I submitted a bug report. Let's see if someone answers. Either way, you get kudos++ !

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix glad I could help. For future reference, and for anyone else encountering this problem, the bug report is [here](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown/issues/404). The response is that this is in fact a bug and a [fix is already pending](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown/issues/405).

Comment: Thanks. That was the bug I created, I have edited your answer to include you comment !